# Possessive adjectives grammar error

Tags: adjetivos, concordancia-gramatical, posesivos

I'm trying to rewrite the sentence below to indicate ownership by using possessive adjectives. I caught the first error with the verb ('son'), but I don't understand the adjective error. In my mind it translates as: "It's their ('sus') tape recorder," so why is the singular ('su') adjective correct? Am I confusing something in agreement?

Sentence to rewrite: "Ellos compran una grabadora."
My Error: "Son sus grabadora."
Correction: "Es su grabadora."

Comment: I think the original sentence would have been *Ellos compran **una** grabadora.*  The noun is feminine, so the article has to match: *una*, not *un*. // To choose between *sus* and *su*: try not to translate word for word, because that might make you go from "their" to "sus" which would be incorrect here.  Instead, start with *grabadora* and notice that it is singular -- that tells you the possessive adjective needs to be singular too: *su*.  In other words, "their" might be expressed as "su" or "sus" depending on whether the noun is singular or plural.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the possesive constructions goes like this:

Verb "ser" , possesive pronoun, subject

Possesive pronuns are

**My**

> Mi, Mis,

Singuar **Your**

> Tu, Tus

**Their** and formal and plural **Your**

> su, sus

**our**

> nuestro,nuestros |nuestra, nuestras

So the construction is

**Es**(The present conjugation of "ser" of the single noun for "grabadora")
**su**(The single possesive pronoun for "their")
**grabadora**

Answer (score 1):

There is only one *grabadora*, hence you use the singular form.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion you are experiencing revolves around what the subject actually is for the sentence. The word "grabadora" is the noun in your sentence, and "su" is a possessive adjective. The possessive adjective is describing the noun, which is singular. Both a possessive and descriptive adjective will reflect the gender and quantity of the subject noun.

Comment: I think this is a bit confusing as you seem to suggest that the recorder is the subject of the sentence whereas I think it is some unspecified plural group of people. Would you like to edit your question to clarify?